Issue with Custom Component in Qt Creator (Works in Qt Design Studio)
I’m working on a project using Qt Design Studio and created a GUI with some custom components. When I run the project directly from Qt Design Studio, everything works fine. However, when I open the same project in Qt Creator, I get the following error:
module "Velocita" is not installed
Where "Velocita" is a custom component I created in Design Studio.
I tried following some advice I found online and added this line to the C++ code:
engine.load(":content/Velocita.ui.qml");
But it didn’t work, it says:
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
Additionally, I’ve noticed that several other imports also have issues when the project is opened in Qt Creator like QtQuick.Studio.Components and QtQuick.Studio.Effects.
Has anyone encountered this type of problem before? Is it common for there to be differences between running in Qt Design Studio and Qt Creator? Any suggestions on how I could resolve this? I might be missing a step to make the custom components available in Qt Creator as well.

That `":content/" syntax is for the Qt resource system and will only work as long as you're using it.
